# Node.js become very slow when adding many async jobs

Tags: node.js

Node.js become very slow when adding many async jobs.
Here is an example:

```
const http = require("http")
http.createServer((req, res) => res.end("ok")).listen(8008)

const n = 100
let x = n

function f(){
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        http.get("http://localhost:8008", res => {
            res.on("data", () => {})
            res.on("end", e => --x || finish())
        })
    }
}
function finish(){
    console.timeEnd("main")
    process.exit()
}
f()

console.time("main")
```

Create server and request to self server.

The result is here.

```
n: 100 -> 79ms
n: 1000 -> 3328ms
n: 10000 -> too long...
```

I tried to separate some parts by adding timeout.

```
const http = require("http")
http.createServer((req, res) => res.end("ok")).listen(8008)

const n = 100
let x = n

async function f(){
    for(let i = 0; i < n / 10; i++){
        for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            http.get("http://localhost:8008", res => {
                res.on("data", () => {})
                res.on("end", e => --x || finish())
            })
        }
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0))
    }
}
function finish(){
    console.timeEnd("main")
    process.exit()
}
f()

console.time("main")
```

The result is here.

```
n: 100 -> 109ms
n: 1000 -> 850ms
n: 10000 -> 3969ms
```

This problem is not limited to http request.

When I send many INSERT query to database server at once, I faced the same problem.
I gave up and stopped the program after ten or more minutes later from the start of execution.
Surprisingly, NO records were inserted into database.
At that time, no transaction was used.
I believe that no INSERT processing has been executed yet.

Does node.js have a problem that it cannot add many jobs to async queue at once?

## Update

I wonder why the first example is very slower than the second example.
The second example shows that the server handle 10000 requests in about 4 seconds.
However, it did not finish after several minutes later in the first example.
The second example has delay.
However, I set timeout 0 ms, so it means almost simultaneous.

Comment: Regarding DB insert try to get the results batched before inserting to DB, the single inserts are killing your performance.

Comment: Are you sure that the server at "http://localhost:8008" is capable to handle such amount of request? I guess the bottleneck is the "http://localhost:8008" server here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node has no specific limits with concurrent async tasks. Side effects of these tasks may cause problems. Thousands of simultaneous requests can make web server or database server choke; this is basically DDoS attack. OS limitations on maximum allowed connections can also apply.

Async tasks should be planned according to the expectations of web server. They could be performed with empirically chosen delay if it's known that web server handles this amount of concurrent requests correctly:

```
function doRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    http.get("http://localhost:8008", res => {
      res.on("data", () => {})
      res.on("error", reject)
      res.on("end", resolve)
    });
  });
}

function doDelay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

async function f(){
  const requests = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const request = doRequest();
    requests.push(request);
    await Promise.race([request, doDelay(100)]);
  }
  return Promise.all(requests);
}
```

Or maximum amount of concurrent requests could be limited:

```
const maxConnections = 20;

async function f(){
  const requests = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (requests.length > maxConnections) {
      const requestIndex = await Promise.race(requests.map(
        async (request, requestIndex) => {
          await request;
          return requestIndex;
        }
      ));
      requests.splice(requestIndex, 1);
    }

    const request = doRequest();
    requests.push(request);
  }
  return Promise.all(requests);
}
```

Notice that in second snippet `f` can only return results of last requests.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.
I wonder why the first example is very slower than the second example.
The second exaple has delay.
However, it is almost simultaneous because timeout is 0ms.

Comment: Because they work differently, likely the delay in snippet 1 is too low, or is too high, or the server cannot handle a stream of requests with constant delay efficiently any way. As it was mentioned, the delay should be set empirically.